# debugging Transactional annotation in Java Spring

Tags: java, spring, annotations

Updating an existing piece of code as shown below:

```
@Override
@Transactional
public void update(SomeObject someObj) throws BusinessServiceException {
    ...
    someObjectRepository1.update(someObj);
    someObjectRepository2.create(someObj);

    //New code below:
    someObjectRelatedService.doStuff(someObj);  // <--new code
    //Throws error, object does not exist in someObjectRepository2
}
```

The issue here is that **someObjectRelatedService.doStuff** needs the latest and most updated version of someObjectRepository2 - but the transactional annotation prevents that from happening, it updates the repository AFTER the method has fully ran. I was able to verify by using a debugger and running a database call in between.

What would be the best way to approach this situation? Is it solely to extract the someObjectRelatedService call outside the transactional method?

Comment: You need to flush your session. Flushing is the process of synchronizing the underlying persistent store with persistable state held in memory

Comment: I would strongly advice against manually flushing the transaction. What you can do instead is: remove `@Transactional` from this method, create a new class with one method, move the `someObjectRepository2.create(someObj);` to this method, make this mehtod `@Transactional`. Note that creating a new `@Transactional` method within the class you are currently in will not work since `this`-calls are not proxied.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In essence, you need to move the boundary of your transaction. While manually flushing the transaction is an option, I would not recommend to do so.

The easiest fix, if the semantics of `SomeObjectRepository2#create(...)` permit it, would be to annotate this method with `@Transactional(isolation = Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW)`.

If this should not be possible, I propose the following minor redesign. First, we create a new class with one method, which should execute the code related to the data that is needed:

```
@Component
public class NewClass {
    final SomeObjectRepository2 someObjectRepository2;

    @Autowired
    public NewClass(final SomeObjectRepository2 someObjectRepository2) {
        this.someObjectRepository2 = someObjectRepository2;
    }

    @Transactional(isolation = Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW) // enforces new transaction
    public WhateverNeedsToBereturned newMethod(WhateverType someObject) {
        return someObjectRepository2.create(someObj);
    }
}
```

And then we rewrite the existing code to use the new class:

```
@Override
@Transactional
public void update(SomeObject someObj) throws BusinessServiceException {
    ...
    someObjectRepository1.update(someObj);
    newClassInstance.newMethod(someObj);

    //New code below:
    someObjectRelatedService.doStuff(someObj); 
    //Throws error, object does not exist in someObjectRepository2
}
```

Note that you have to create a new class in order for this to work. Method calls through the `this`-reference are not proxied and thus the `@Transactional` annotation does not take effect.

Note further that `newClassInstance` must be injected through the DI container for the same reason.

Comment: At first I attempted moving the functionality to a separate transactional method, and assumed that resolved the issue. But calling a transactional method internally within the class no longer makes it transactional. This approach seems like the best one. Thanks.

Comment: As I said: `this`-calls are not proxied, thus `this.someMethod(...)`  won't obey transactions, even if `someMethod(...)` is annotated.